# Google Maps API V2. Быстрая отрисовка большого количества залитых кругов?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Добрый день.

Потребовалось нарисовать на карте много (2500+) кругов разного диаметра и разного цвета.

1. Стандартный способ: map.addCircle(new CircleOptions(...)) оказался ужасно медленным *уже при 1000 объектов, карта очень сильно тормозит даже на Nexus 5.*
2. Написать свой TileProvider? Способ хороший.
   Но как отрисовать на тайлах круги **разного диаметра**, так, чтобы при переходе от тайла к тайлу не отсекалась часть круга?

Подскажите пожалуйста.